# Is there a way to force solr query to not use cache?

Tags: caching, search, solr, lucene

Suppose I execute the same SOLR query multiple times, is there a way to specify in the query to force SOLR so that it doesn't use the cache and therefore subsequent runs of the same query will have roughly the same amount of QTime instead of having one query have long QTime at the first time and then on the second run it ends up showing in 1 ms....

hint: I'm looking for something similar to SQL_NO_CACHE in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `{!cache=false}` localParam flag as mentioned in the [Solr caching wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching)

Comment: isn't that just going to disable filterCache....what about other caches such as queryResultCache

Comment: Yup, that's right. Believe you can control other caches only globally via solr-config as mentioned in the wiki. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#Disabling_Caching. And even then lucene's FieldCache cannot be configured via Solr.